# Unix Shell Script loop can execute only once

Tags: shell, unix, ftp, backup, sh

I have a problem with my shell script that should be uploaded the backup files into FTP servers

I create a for loop to execute ftp function but unfortunately it's work only once.

Can anyone help ?  thank in advance.

```
#!/bin/sh
# FTP Backup
# Version : 2.0
# Updated : 03/04/2014

#MONITOR MODE
TSCMON=off

echo "-------- FTP BACKUP v2 --------"
echo "#         version 2.0         #"
echo "-------------------------------"


doFTP () {
        echo "Invoking doFTP()"
        echo "doFTP()->IP=$1->USR->$2->PWD->$3"

        declare -a sFILESET=("${!7}")
        #echo "DEBUGGGGGGGGG -------------------> ${sFILESET[@]}"

        echo "#!/bin/sh" > client.ftp
        echo " FILECOUNT= $6"
        echo "/usr/bin/ftp -inv $1 << END_SCRIPT" >> client.ftp
        echo "quote USER $2" >> client.ftp
        echo "quote PASS $3" >> client.ftp
        echo "lcd $4" >> client.ftp
        echo "mkdir $5" >> client.ftp
        echo "cd $5" >> client.ftp

        for ((i=0;i<$6;i++)); do
                #echo "DEBUG i=$i"
                echo " UPLOADING FILE -->  ${sFILESET[$i]}"
                echo "mput ${sFILESET[$i]}" >> client.ftp
        done

        echo "bye" >> client.ftp
        echo "END_SCRIPT" >> client.ftp
        chmod 755 client.ftp
        ./client.ftp
}


#Export Environment
HOST=$(hostname)
IP=$(/sbin/ifconfig  | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')
DBSID=$ORACLE_SID
LOCALPATH='/orabackup'
DESTPATH="${HOST}_${IP}/${DBSID}/export"
echo "--> Exporting Environment ..."


#DATE CONFIGURATION
dtoday=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
dyesterday=$(date --date="-1 day" +"%Y%m%d")
echo "--> Declaring DATE CONFIGURATION ..."
echo " TODAY = ${dtoday}"
echo " YESTERDAY = ${dyesterday}"


#FILE CONFIGURATION
declare -a FILESET
echo "--> Declaring FILE CONFIGURATION ..."
# Added by iPattZ 10Apr2014 : Supported Wildcard *#
FILESET[${#FILESET[@]}]="bfile_${dyesterday}.log.gz"
#FILESET[${#FILESET[@]}]="bfile_${dyesterday}.dmp.gz"
echo " FILESET.SIZE-> ${#FILESET[*]}"
echo " FILESET.VAL-> ${FILESET[*]}"


#FTP CONFIGURATION
declare -a FTPHOST
echo "--> Declaring FTP CONFIGURATION ..."
FTPHOST[${#FTPHOST[@]}]='192.168.1.199;myuser;mypass
FTPHOST[${#FTPHOST[@]}]='192.168.1.200;myuser;mypass
FTPCNT=${#FTPHOST[@]}
echo " Found FTP Server : ${FTPCNT}"
#echo "DEBUG : FTP String : ${FTPHOST[@]}"

for ((i=0;i<FTPCNT;i++)); do

        echo "--> FTP No.$(($i+1)) : Connecting ..."

        IFS=';' read -a j <<< "${FTPHOST[i]}"
        sFTPIP=${j[0]}
        sFTPUSR=${j[1]}
        sFTPPWD=${j[2]}
        sFILECNT=${#FILESET[*]}
        echo " FTPIP->${sFTPIP}"
        echo " FTPUSR=${sFTPUSR}"
        #echo "DEBUG sFILECNT=${sFILECNT}"
        #echo "DEBUG FTPPWD=${sFTPPWD}"

        doFTP $sFTPIP $sFTPUSR $sFTPPWD $LOCALPATH $DESTPATH $sFILECNT "FILESET[@]"
done
```

Comment: In general, `/bin/sh` does not support that style of `for` loop, or arrays for that matter. You should change the shebang to `!#/bin/bash`, or stick to POSIX-compliant code.

Comment: Also, you appear to be missing the closing single quote for your assignment to `FTPHOST`, although that should just trigger a different error at some point, without executing your loop at all.

Comment: +1 for way---yyyy better than usual first post. You actually have some interesting code. Sorry, I don't have time to look to deep into right now. Good luck!

Comment: @chepner Thanks for your advise, how ever after I has changed shebang from "#!/bin/sh" to "#!/bin/bash" it still work only first time in the loop. What I just need is to make that script ftp file into 2 sites of FTP Server.

Comment: After I try to debug my code, I found that the iteration was broken by nested for loop in doFTP() function. 

After I comment out the following code #for ((i=0;i<$6;i++)); do
        #       #echo "DEBUG i=$i"
        #       echo " UPLOADING FILE -->  ${sFILESET[$i]}"
        #       echo "mput ${sFILESET[$i]}" >> client.ftp
        #done
The script was working as propery, What is my mistake can anyone help ?

Comment: Dear all, I just made a stupid mistake (- -") I didn't declare variable "i" as a local variable then It was overwrite the value in global one that make my first for loop to stop the interation. After I changed it to local it working as properly now. Anyway thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

The loop index `i` is used in both `doFTP` and your main script. The first time `doFTP` is called, `i` is eventually set to whatever `$6` is for that call, which is most likely greater than the value of `FTPCNT`, causing your exit condition for the outer loop to be satisfied the next time it is checked. Just use a different variable as the index for each loop.